# Can't import import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

Tags: angular

I am using Angular cli:

> Angular CLI: 6.0.3 Node: 8.10.0 OS: win32 x64 Angular: 6.0.3 ...
>   animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms ... http,
>   language-service, platform-browser ... platform-browser-dynamic,
>   router
>
> Package                           Version
>   ----------------------------------------------------------- @angular-devkit/architect         0.6.3 @angular-devkit/build-angular 
>   0.6.3 @angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.3 @angular-devkit/core              0.6.3 @angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.3 @ngtools/webpack                  6.0.3 @schematics/angular               0.6.3 @schematics/update                0.6.3 rxjs                              6.2.0 typescript                        2.7.2 webpack                           4.8.3

And I am using Angular verison 6:

> Your global Angular CLI version (6.0.5) is greater than your local
>   version (6.0.3). The local Angular CLI version is used.
>
> To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch
>   false".

But what ever I try visual studio code still says:

> ERROR in ./src/app/_services/auth.service.ts Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve './rxjs-operators' in 'D:\DatingApp\src\app_services' i
>   ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

And this is my code:

```
// import { map, filter, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import './rxjs-operators';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response} from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
// import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable()

export class AuthService {
  baseUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/api/auth';
  userToken:  any;


constructor(private http: Http) { }

login(model: any) {
  const headers = new Headers({'Content-type': 'application/json'});
  const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
  return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'login', model, options).pipe(map(response => {

    const user = response.json();
    if (user) {
      localStorage.setItem('token', user.tokenString);
      this.userToken = user.tokenString;

    }
  }));
  }

}
```

So what is the solution that angular can recognise the:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Thank you

And this is my app.module.ts:

```
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ValueComponent } from './value/value.component';
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ValueComponent,
    NavComponent
],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
  HttpModule,
  FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [AuthService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Oke, I changed to this:

```
import { FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ValueComponent } from './value/value.component';
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ValueComponent,
    NavComponent
],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [AuthService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Oke, I changed to this:

```
// import { map, filter, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import './rxjs-operators';
import {Headers, RequestOptions, Response} from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
// import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable()

export class AuthService {
  baseUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/api/auth';
  userToken:  any;


constructor(private http: HttpClient ) { }

login(model: any) {
  const headers = new Headers({'Content-type': 'application/json'});
  const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
  return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'login', model, options).pipe(map(response => {

    const user = response.json();
    if (user) {
      localStorage.setItem('token', user.tokenString);
      this.userToken = user.tokenString;

    }
  }));
  }

}
```

But now I get two compiler errors:

> ERROR in src/app/services/auth.service.ts(23,56): error TS2345:
>   Argument of type 'RequestOptions' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[];
>   }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.   Types of property 'headers'
>   are incompatible.
>       Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
>         Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
>           Index signature is missing in type 'Headers'. src/app/services/auth.service.ts(25,27): error TS2339: Property 'json'
>   does not exist on type '{}'.

Comment: The path `D:\DatingApp\src\app_services` is probably wrong, I'm guessing this folder does not exist, right ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But I just created a folder _service in the folder app folder and in the _service  folder I created a new service. What I have to change then?

Comment: Would you mind trying to remove the leading underscore from your service folder ? Then adapting your imports ?

Comment: Your import looks correct apart from it is there any specific reason for using deprecated `HttpModule` in your application.

Comment: YOu mean this: import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response} from '@angular/http'; Yes, because I am using Dependency injection:constructor(private http: Http) { } see the code I have posted

Comment: Oke, I have done that. But I still get the error: ERROR in ./src/app/services/auth.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './rxjs-operators' in 'D:\DatingApp\src\app\services'. I also closed/open Visual studio code

Comment: it's not about DI mate you should use `HttpClientModule` because `HttpModule` is deprecated [Refer this](https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2017/07/17/http-client-module/)

Comment: This time the folder is correct but your build process shouldn't look into `D:\DatingApp\src\app\services` but in `D:\DatingApp\node_modules`

Comment: Oke, I changed the app.module.ts file. But what else I have to change? Thank you

Comment: @ YoukouleleY ok. And how to do that?

Comment: I think @Vikas is right, `HttpModule` is deprecated and uses an old version of RxJS that is probably not present in your `node_modules`, try importing `HttpClientModule` instead

Comment: @ YoukouleleY I have done that see the code I posted.

Comment: You also have to change from `constructor(private http: Http)` to  `constructor(private http: HttpClient)`

Comment: Refer [Migrating to HttpClient](http://brianflove.com/2017/07/21/migrating-to-http-client/)

Comment: Just remove the import that the error is **actually** complaining about: `Can't resolve './rxjs-operators'`. So you need to remove `import './rxjs-operators';`.

Comment: I edit the post. Can you check it

Comment: Don't use anything from '@angular/http'. This is deprecated, and not compatible with the newer HttpClient. Read its documentation: https://angular.io/guide/http, https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient

Comment: ? Oh , oke. BUt can you show then how the auth.service.ts file should look like. WIll be nice

Comment: The documentation will tell you that. Read it.

Comment: Better if you show me. Because now everybody says something else. SO would be nice if you post the correct code here in stackflow. Then it is solved. Because I don't know it. And if you can do it and want to help then you just post the correct syntax and I can try it here local and if it works it is solved :)

Comment: @JB Nizet - if you are a beginner you can just say it. Don't shame for it. Everybody has to start somewhere. But I solved and it has nothing to do with http - that it was incorrect. Just imported the correct liberary  and it works now!! My advise for you: read better the documentation of Angular. and I hope you will better understand how Angular works. So take little steps and maybe some day you will have the same level as me - a professional with a big passion. Have a nice day anyway

Comment: @absoluteProgramming I have read the documentation, thank you. I've actually teached Angular to dozens of programmers, for a living, and helped writing a book about it. If you're really "a professional with a big passion", then you should definitely learn to read. 1. The error message, which told you what was wrong with your imports. 2. My comment, which told you what import to remove. 3. The documentation, which clearly explains how to use HttpClient.

Comment: In my case, VS Code did not recognize map until I added the "/operators" to the import statement. Then it worked.

Answer (score 6):

Try installing rxjs-compat:

`npm i --save rxjs-compat`

And then import it like so: `import 'rxjs-compat'`

I know with Angular 6, some dependencies need the compat library to use these rxjs operators.

In previous versions the import was `import 'rxjs/add/operators/map'`

I also believe the new import syntax is:
`import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`